# How to group array objects by one of their fields?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter

I'm trying to restructure an array by filtering it from another list of array.

**Array Containing Filters:**

```
const filteringTags: [
    'Kitchen',
    'Accessories',
    ...
]
```

**Array I Would Like to Manipulate:**

```
[
    {
        category: 'free',
        date: '2020-04-04',
        title: 'Some Title',
        tags: [
            'Kitchen',
            'Accessories'
        ]
    },
    {
        category: 'premium',
        date: '2020-04-05',
        title: 'Another Title',
        tags: [
            'Kitchen'
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

**Expected Result:**

```
[
    'Kitchen': [
        {
            category: 'free',
            date: '2020-04-04',
            title: 'Some Title',
            tags: [
                'Kitchen',
                'Accessories'
            ]
        },
        {
            category: 'premium',
            date: '2020-04-05',
            title: 'Another Title',
            tags: [
                'Kitchen'
            ]
        }
    ],
    'Accessories': [
        {
            category: 'free',
            date: '2020-04-04',
            title: 'Some Title',
            tags: [
                'Kitchen',
                'Accessories'
            ]
        }
    ]
]
```

I'm trying to avoid using libraries so if you have any suggestions I would appreciate if you use vanilla JS.

Comment: *"... nothing useful to post here"*. Post it anyway - it shows effort, which makes it much likely someone will help.

Comment: Looks like Expected result is not a valid JSON object. Is It array of objects or just an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the required output as array of objects,

```js
const data = [
  {
    category: 'free',
    date: '2020-04-04',
    title: 'Some Title',
    tags: ['Kitchen', 'Accessories'],
  },
  {
    category: 'premium',
    date: '2020-04-05',
    title: 'Another Title',
    tags: ['Kitchen'],
  },
];

const filteringTags = ['Kitchen', 'Accessories'];

const getGroupedData = (data, filters) => {
  const result = {};
  filters.forEach(filter => {
    result[filter] = [
      ...JSON.parse(JSON.stringify((result[filter] || ''))),
      ...JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.filter(d => d.tags.includes(filter)))),
    ];
  });
  return result;
};

let finalResult = getGroupedData(data, filteringTags);

finalResult = Object.keys(finalResult).map(key => ({
  [key]: finalResult[key],
}));

console.log(finalResult);
```

Considering the output as object

```js
const data = [
  {
    category: 'free',
    date: '2020-04-04',
    title: 'Some Title',
    tags: ['Kitchen', 'Accessories'],
  },
  {
    category: 'premium',
    date: '2020-04-05',
    title: 'Another Title',
    tags: ['Kitchen'],
  },
];

const filteringTags = ['Kitchen', 'Accessories'];

const getGroupedData = (data, filters) => {
  const result = {};
  filters.forEach(filter => {
    result[filter] = [
      ...JSON.parse(JSON.stringify((result[filter] || ''))),
      ...JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.filter(d => d.tags.includes(filter)))),
    ];
  });
  return result;
};

let finalResult = getGroupedData(data, filteringTags);

console.log(finalResult);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: There's a serious problem of circular reference here. If you modify `kitchen[0].category `, the category of `Accessories` will be changed too.

Comment: I agree @ABGR. Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated the answer with the fix.

Answer (score 1):

```
const filteringTags = [
  'Kitchen',
  'Accessories',
] 

const arr = [
  {
    category: 'free',
    date: '2020-04-04',
    title: 'Some Title',
    tags: [
        'Kitchen',
        'Accessories'
    ]
},
{
    category: 'premium',
    date: '2020-04-05',
    title: 'Another Title',
    tags: [
        'Kitchen'
    ]
}
]

const resultArr = filteringTags.map((it, index) => {
  return { [it]: arr }
})
```

If you need object, so use this function

```
const resultObj = filteringTags.reduce((acc, it) => {
  return { ...acc, [it]: arr }
}, {})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full working example which produces the desired result:

```js
const filteringTags = [
    'Kitchen',
    'Accessories',
];

const data = [
    {
        category: 'free',
        date: '2020-04-04',
        title: 'Some Title',
        tags: [
            'Kitchen',
            'Accessories'
        ]
    },
    {
        category: 'premium',
        date: '2020-04-05',
        title: 'Another Title',
        tags: [
            'Kitchen'
        ]
    },
];

function byTag(tags, data) {
  let tagMap = {};
  for (let tag of tags) {
    tagMap[tag] = [];
    for (let datum of data) {
       if (datum.tags.includes(tag)) {
          tagMap[tag].push(datum);
       }
    }
  }
  return tagMap;
}

let result = byTag(filteringTags, data);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Comment: There you're going for something like O(N3)

Comment: @ABGR if there are N data items and M tags the solution above is O(N*M). I have no clue where you got O(N^3) from.

Comment: N*M is still considered as n^2. Plus You're ignoring there's `includes`  too which together make it three passes, hence 0(N^3). Anyway no offence :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
var arr = [
    {
        category: 'free',
        date: '2020-04-04',
        title: 'Some Title',
        tags: [
            'Kitchen',
            'Accessories'
        ]
    },
    {
        category: 'premium',
        date: '2020-04-05',
        title: 'Another Title',
        tags: [
            'Kitchen'
        ]
    },
];

var res = arr.reduce((acc, elem)=>{
 elem.tags.forEach(k=>{
    acc[k] = acc[k] ? [...acc[k], JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(elem))] : [JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(elem))];
 })
 return acc
},{});

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with :

- `reduce()`
- `filter()`

```js
var filteringTags= [ 'Kitchen', 'Accessories'];

var arr=[ { category: 'free', date: '2020-04-04', title: 'Some Title', tags: [ 'Kitchen', 'Accessories' ] }, { category: 'premium', date: '2020-04-05', title: 'Another Title', tags: [ 'Kitchen' ] }];

var result = filteringTags.reduce((acc, e)=>{
    acc[e] = arr.filter(k=>k.tags.includes(e));
    return acc;
},{});

console.log(result);
```